# NDIS Hooking for Blocking/Unblocking website on windows xp

Tags: firewall, hook, ndis

I am trying to block/unblock some of website on windows xp using NDIS Hooking.I am new for this NDIS Hooking on windows xp. so can you please tell whether is there any sample in msdn or do you have any sample application whick can  Block/Unblock website.

Thanks,
Kamal.

Comment: Belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary conversion.

1. Get its IP address (216.178.39.74), by pinging the name (if you have a direct internet connection) or if you only have access via a web proxy then find it out by using a networking website like network-tools. com.
2. Start your PC's calculator, and change it to scientific mode (using the "View" menu)
3. Enter each of the four IP octets, one by one, converting them to binary (enter number and click on the "Bin" radio button)

   Thus 216.178.39.74 becomes

   ```
   216 = 11011000
   178 = 10110010
   39 = 00100111
   74 = 01001010
   ```

   Notice how any binary numbers less than 8 digits long have had leading zeroes added to pad them out. Reassembled into IP address order, you get

   ```
   11011000.10110010. 00100111. 01001010
   ```
4. Remove the dots, so you get one huge line of binary, thus:

   ```
   1101100010110010001 0011101001010
   ```
5. Copy this binary string
6. Go to your scientific calculator, and hit the "Bin" button FIRST (as you are about to enter binary), THEN paste in the binary string.
7. Click on the "Dec" button on your calculator, and you will get the converted value of `3635554122`
8. Add the hypertext protocol prefix and paste into your browser's address bar:

   http://3635554122